# unable to re-attach screen session on freebsd

Tags: display, freebsd

I have a screen session that I am unable to re-attach to.
I have tried kill -CHLD 6859, with zero success.

Is there anything else that I can try to get this session re-attached

```
q4# screen -ls
No Sockets found in /tmp/screens/S-root.

q4# ls -la /tmp/screens/S-root/
total 8
drwx------  2 root  wheel  512 May 26 12:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  512 Feb 26  2013 ..
prwx------  1 root  wheel    0 May 26 10:14 6859.pts-0.q4
q4# ps uax 6859
USER  PID %CPU %MEM   VSZ   RSS TT  STAT STARTED     TIME COMMAND
root 6859  0.0  1.2 84732 50444 ??  Ss    2Jan13 34:06.71 screen -h 9999
q4# screen -r
There is no screen to be resumed.
q4# whoami
root
q4#
```

Answer (score 0):

did you su - to become root? I've found that if you did, this prevents you running screen for some reason. Try logging in as root and then screen -r